# Activate/deactivate conda virtualenvs on entering/leaving directories

Tags: bash, anaconda, conda

[`pyenv-virtualenv`](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv#activate-virtualenv) offers a nice way of activating the environment on the very instant of entering or leaving the directory which contains a `.python-version` text file which specifies the environment to activate. It works for the directory it is in and all directories contained in it.

The environment is deactivated once we change the directory to something above it. This allows to easily switch between projects or analyses using different python versions (just by changing the directories).

Is there a way of achieving the same behaviour with (ana)conda?

Edit: added bash tag, because - as far as I understand - pyenv achieves this by hooking a custom script into `.bashrc` (which allows it to monitor the directory changes). If there is no build-in way in conda, how to create a script which would make it possible?

Comment: According to [this](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/5179) issue there is currently no officially supported way to do this, however in that discussion you'll find links to 3rd-party bash/zsh solutions that'll work.

Comment: Thank you. I think that a short explanation of the autoenv, or of the code in the blog post linked in that thread would make for a great answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, this is currently not supported. There is however an open issue on [conda's GitHub](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/5179) asking for this feature.

In the meantime you could use [autoenv](https://github.com/inishchith/autoenv), a small tool that'll automatically run the code in a `.env` file when entering a directory and that in a `.env.leave` when leaving the directory (supports bash/zsh and a couple others).

A simple example taken from their readme which illustrates the feature quite nicely:

```
$ echo "echo 'whoa'" > project/.env
$ cd project
whoa
```

To load a conda environment your `.env` would simply look like this:

```
conda activate <my_env>
```

Note 1: Check out the *Configuration* section of their GitHub readme before you start using it.

Note 2: The author of *autoenv* actually suggests trying [direnv](https://github.com/direnv/direnv) instead. However I've never used it, so I can't comment on it.

From *autoenv*'s readme:

> you should probably use direnv instead. Simply put, it is higher quality software. But, autoenv is still great, too. Maybe try both? :)