# How to run Jupyter Lab directly without activating every time? (Python- Jupyter Lab)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I have to run 'venv\Sources\activate' command every time before run the Jupyter Lab command. As my jupyter is installed on virtual environment, I want to run Jupyter Lab from my project path directly without activating every time. Is this even possible?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nr2Bw.png)

Comment: While this doesn't answer your question, you could consider [aliasing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/set-alias?view=powershell-7.2) 'venv\Sources\activate' to something shorter of your choosing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Activate/deactivate conda virtualenvs on entering/leaving directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58824674/activate-deactivate-conda-virtualenvs-on-entering-leaving-directories)

Comment: @ezrathescribe I just created a dot bat file and just put this two commands together and it worked. 'source\venv\Scripts\activate & jupyter notebook'

Comment: @krassowski I was actually looking for a easy way and as my jupyter is installed only on my venv/Scripts, I can only activate with the following link. Actually I needed to activate and run together with one cmd.

Answer (score 0):

I created a dot bat file and put these two commands together for activating and run jupyter together. If you get something more useful than this, please knock me up!
'source\venv\Scripts\activate & jupyter notebook'